# Help with MLP convergence

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, mlp, implementation, convergence

I posted [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/14302/help-with-mlp-convergence) question on AI SE and got advised to ask here for guidance. I've been stuck for a couple of days trying to figure it out how the standard MLP works and why my code doesn't converge at all to solve `XOR` (doesn't breaks as well and produce some numbers). To make things short and straightforward (you can get more details in the above link), I'm stuck at coding backpropagation with a simple architecture ($1$ hidden layer) in a small library written in `C#` and the source code can be found [here](https://github.com/ivansnpmaster/SNNP).

To update the output's weights, I followed the next equation:

$$
\frac{\partial E^2}{\partial w_{kj}}=-2\cdot(y_k-\hat{y_k})\cdot
            \underbrace{\frac{\partial f_k^o}{\partial net_k^o}}_{f'_k(net_k^o)} \cdot
            \underbrace{\frac{\partial net_k^o}{\partial w_{kj}}}_{f_j(net_j^h)}
$$

The output's biases:

$$\frac{\partial E^2}{\partial b_k} = -2 \cdot (y_k-\hat{y_k}) \cdot \frac{\partial f_k^o}{\partial net_k^o}\cdot1$$

And to update the hidden layer's weights:

$$
\frac{\partial E^2}{\partial w_{ji}}=-2\cdot(y_k-\hat{y_k}) \cdot
          \underbrace{\frac{\partial f_k^o}{\partial net_k^o}}_{f'_k(net_k^o)} \cdot
          \underbrace{\frac{\partial net_k^o}{\partial f_j^h}}_{(w_k^o)^T} \cdot
          \underbrace{\frac{\partial f_j^h}{\partial net_j^h}}_{f'_j(net_j^h)} \cdot
          \underbrace{\frac{\partial net_j^h}{\partial w_{ji}}}_{x_i}
$$

And the hidden layer's biases:

$$
\frac{\partial E^2}{\partial b_j^h}=-2\cdot(y_k-\hat{y_k}) \cdot
          \underbrace{\frac{\partial f_k^o}{\partial net_k^o}}_{f'_k(net_k^o)} \cdot
          \underbrace{\frac{\partial net_k^o}{\partial f_j^h}}_{(w_k^o)^T} \cdot
          \underbrace{\frac{\partial f_j^h}{\partial net_j^h}}_{f'_j(net_j^h)} \cdot
          \underbrace{\frac{\partial net_j^h}{\partial b_j^h}}_{1}
$$

The dataset that I'm using to train:

```cs
double[,] dataset = { {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1} };
```

The actual backpropagation:

```cs
public List<double> Backpropagation(double[,] dataset, double eta = 0.01, double threshold = 1e-5)
{
    List<double> ret = new List<double>();

    double rows = dataset.GetLength(0);

    const int number_iter = 500000;
    int counter = 0;

    double squaredError = 2 * threshold;

    while (counter < number_iter && squaredError > threshold)
    {
        squaredError = 0;
        counter++;

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            double[] xp = new double[i_n];

            for (int j = 0; j < xp.Length; j++)
                xp[j] = dataset[i, j];

            double[] yp = new double[dataset.GetLength(1) - i_n]; // number of outputs expected

            for (int j = 0; j < yp.Length; j++)
                yp[j] = dataset[i, i_n + j];

            Matrix Yp = new Matrix(yp); // column based matrix

            var ff = Feedforward(xp);

            Matrix[] net = ff.Item1;
            Matrix[] fnet = ff.Item2;
            Matrix i_m = ff.Item3;

            Matrix Op = fnet[fnet.Length - 1];

            Matrix error = Op - Yp;

            squaredError += error.SquaredSum();

            // Backpropagation

            // % hadamard product, * matrix multiplication

            Matrix error_o = (-2 * error) % Matrix.Map(fnet[fnet.Length - 1], da_f);

            Matrix error_h = (Matrix.T(w[w.Length - 1]) * error_o) % Matrix.Map(fnet[fnet.Length - 2], da_f);

            Matrix gradient_wo = error_o * Matrix.T(fnet[fnet.Length - 2]);
            Matrix gradient_bo = error_o;

            Matrix gradient_wh = error_h * Matrix.T(i_m);
            Matrix gradient_bh = error_h;

            w[1] = w[1] - (eta * gradient_wo);
            b[1] = b[1] - (eta * gradient_bo);

            w[0] = w[0] - (eta * gradient_wh);
            b[0] = b[0] - (eta * gradient_bh);
        }

        squaredError /= rows;

        ret.Add(squaredError);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

I'm using $2$ criterias to stop the algorithm:

1. number of iterations
2. mean squared error bellow a given threshold

The `Matrix.Map` function just loops through the spots in the matrix and apply a given function `da_f` to each spot (in this case, the sigmoid's derivative).

Running the algorithm the `squaredError` variable got stuck every time around $0.5$ with $2$ hidden neurons (It actually do not reaches $0.5$, but gets pretty close). I tried to increase the number of hidden neurons to something like $9$ but nothing changed. It continued to converge to $0.5$, even when tuning the $\eta$ from $0.01$ to $0.2$. With $2$ neurons in the hidden layer the `squaredError` produced the following curve:

[image: Error x iterations]

Using the `Feedforward` for `XOR` inputs with $2$ hidden layers after the backpropagation proccess produces the following:

```
1 1 0.953206137420423
1 0 0.889913390479977
0 0 0.846650110272423
0 1 0.932942164537037
```

What I'm doing wrong to produce this kind of behaviour? Any hint is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.